# what is difference anyasync and where in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

what is difference anyasync and where in linq?
Is this same `Where(pr => pr.RegistoId == registoId && pr.HoraFim == null)` ?

```
public async Task<bool> IsParagemOnGoingAsync(int registoId)
    {
       return await _context.ParagensRegistos
           .Where(pr => pr.RegistoId == registoId)
           .AnyAsync(pr => pr.HoraFim == null);
    }
```

Comment: Log the generated query, or use the SQL Server Profiler (assuming you're going to Sql Server) to inspect the generated query. Compare the two.

Comment: `Where` doesn't execute the query, it returns a new query with a `Where` clause. You'd still need to call `.Any()` or `.AnyAsync()`. `Any(redicate)` or `AnyAsync(predicate)` are *probably* the same as `Where(predicate).Any()` and `Where(predicate).AnyAsync()`, assuming the underlying provider generates the same SQL. For simple queries, it should

Comment: @RyanWilson `Where` will return a new IQueryable query, it won't execute anything